# Laravel Eloquent/QueryBuilder Multiple Nested Selects

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

how would i write query like these in eloquent/query builder ?, queries where there are multiple nested select statements with joins.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Select
          s.user_id,
          s.user_name,
          s.`user_firstname`,
          s.`user_lastname`,
          s.user_photo,
          max_rank_timestamp,
          max_friend_timestamp
    FROM
          (
            SELECT
              Users.user_id,
              Users.`user_name`,
              Users.`user_firstname`,
              Users.`user_lastname`,
              `Users`.`user_photo`,
              MAX(Ranks.rank_timestamp) AS max_rank_timestamp
            FROM
              `Users`
              LEFT JOIN Ranks ON Ranks.user_id = Users.user_id
            WHERE
              Users.user_is_active = 1
            GROUP BY
              Users.user_id
          ) s
          LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT
                        Users.user_id,
                        MAX(Relationship.timestamp) AS max_friend_timestamp
                      FROM
                        `Users`
                        INNER JOIN Relationship ON Relationship.user_one_id = Users.user_id
                      WHERE
                        Users.user_is_active = 1
                      GROUP BY
                        Users.user_id
                    ) p ON s.user_id = p.user_id
      ) t
    ORDER BY
      `user_name` ASC
```

User Model

```
public function ranks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rank','user_id','user_id');
}

public function relationships(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Relationship','user_one_id','user_id');
}
```

Rank Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_id');
}
```

Relationship Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_one_id');
}
```

Comment: Do you have the relationships for `Relationship` and `Ranks` set up on your user model?

Comment: yes i the relationships on user model.

Comment: There is one to many relation for both rank and relationship from user. @RossWilson

Comment: Can you show those relationships?

Comment: @RossWilson i have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to add the following scopes to your `User` model:

```
public function scopeWithMaxRankTimestamp(Builder $query)
{
    if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $query->select([$query->getQuery()->from . '.*']);
    }

    $relation = Relation::noConstraints(function () {
        return $this->ranks();
    });

    $q = $this->ranks()->getRelationExistenceQuery(
        $relation->getRelated()->newQuery(), $query, new Expression('MAX(rank_timestamp)')
    );

    $query->selectSub($q->toBase(), 'max_rank_timestamp');
}

public function scopeWithMaxFriendTimestamp(Builder $query)
{
    if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $query->select([$query->getQuery()->from . '.*']);
    }

    $relation = Relation::noConstraints(function () {
        return $this->relationships();
    });

    $q = $this->relationships()->getRelationExistenceQuery(
        $relation->getRelated()->newQuery(), $query, new Expression('MAX(timestamp)')
    );

    $query->selectSub($q->toBase(), 'max_friend_timestamp');
}
```

The above assumed that the relationship for the `Ranks` table is `ranks()` and the relationship for `Relationship` table is `relationships()`.

For the above to work you will also need to add the following `use` statements to the top of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
```

Then you could use your results like so:

```
$users = User::withMaxRankTimestamp()
    ->withMaxFriendTimestamp()
    ->where('user_is_active', 1)
    ->orderBy('user_name')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps!